# Hypothesis testing in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, hypothesis-test

Im currently doing linear regression for data set. I need to test hypothesis H0:B1=0 vs H1:B1=/=0 for significance lvl a = 0.05 and find p-value. I run command `summary(lm(y~x~))` and the `p-value was 0.02781` However when I tried `t.test(x,y)` I got `p-value = 5.71e-15` Why is that?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

the p-value of the summary corresponds to the t-test of the beta of your regression model. If you run t.test(x,y) you test whether the means of x and y are equal to each other, that has nothing to do with the test whether B1 is equal/unequal to zero.